# Calling a SOAP service (WCF) from Angular

Tags: angular, wcf, soap

I'm building a test page that needs to call a WCF service that does not support REST or JSON, only SOAP with XML.

Is there a library for Angular 2++ for calling SOAP services? Because all I can find is examples that simply do HTTP GET to REST-based services.

Comment: No reason to use an Angular specific library

Comment: So what is the solution then, if it is not an Angular-specific library?

Comment: JavaScript. Find a high quality/recommended JavaScript library, install it, possibly write a basic wrapper, and use it.

Comment: https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap